# "value" argument must not be a number

Tags: javascript, node.js, type-conversion, buffer

I'm trying to convert this array:

```
var receive_data = [];
receive_data[0] = [0x02, "0201010000000000000000000000", 0x03, 0x01];
receive_data[1] = [0x02, '0201020006FF03000000002A0000', 0x03, 't'];
```

to a buffer like this:

```
const buf1 = Buffer.from(parseInt(receive_data[0][0], 16));
const buf2 = Buffer.from(receive_data[0][1].toString());
const buf3 = Buffer.from(receive_data[0][2]);
```

buf2 is working, but i cannot convert buf1 or buf3, i get this error:

> throw new TypeError('"value" argument must not be a number');

Any ideas on what can be happening?

Thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind... i just found the answer, my value must be an array so i need to cast it like this:

```
const buf1 = Buffer.from([receive_data[0][0]]);
```